# Webpage optimization: Should CSS and JS be inserted into the HTML resource after minification?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

Squishing all the JS and all the CSS into single minified files and linking to them from the HTML page is a reasonable way to go and this appears to be the place that a lot of websites take their optimization to.

However I seldom see a website which has *just one* resource load.

My question is about whether having three resources like this is *exactly the same* as taking the contents of them and putting it into the tags to produce one single resource to load. For JS this is straightforward with the `<script>` tags (take out `src` and put the minified JS into the tag), and for CSS this is simply replacing `<link rel="stylesheet" ... />` with `<style type="text/css" /> ...minified CSS... </style>`.

Is this a common practice to squeeze the page into the smallest package possible (One single TCP transaction, hopefully)?

If nothing else it drastically simplifies the job of the webserver software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same to have linked resources and to embed them in the html page.
However not convenient to use on multiple pages.
Then you have to repeat yourself.

If you put all scripts and css together keep this in mind:

> In most cases, the bulk of the JavaScript code handles user-initiated events, such as mouse-clicking and dragging. All of these user-triggered events occur after the page is loaded and the onload event is triggered. In order to defer loading of these JavaScripts insert a JavaScript event listener in the head of the containing document that forces the external file to be loaded after the onload event. 
>   ( [Google developers tips](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) )

This is the code-example to make it more clear, the delaying scripts will be loading after the essential page elements have been formed:

```
 // Add a script element as a child of the body
 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "deferredfunctions.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 // Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Comment: Yes, but say for a single page web-app this doesn't apply.

Comment: That tip about deferring deferrable JS code makes a good point though! This actually made me realize, the biggest perceived impact of loading a page is usually when the initial load happens and content is first seen. In my case 99% of the content is dynamic (JS-built), so it will be straightforward to defer the majority of that to get loaded by the browser after initially presenting some text content (e.g.. `Loading` perhaps) for ultimate initial pageload speed.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep them separate for these two reasons:

1. the browser can use multiple sockets to download the content
2. scripts/stylesheets can be cached an reused in other html pages and will therefore only be downloaded once

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this wouldn't hurt for speed optimisation for devices such as mobiles however on broadband connections it wouldn't make to much difference (obviously speed is a good optimisation and I'm not saying is not) but from what I have read isn't it better to server all content/images from multiple servers where possible as well as code optimisation? Mumford content will save on total page size. But I assumed it didn't matter if the code was on page or through a src file aslong as you don't have multiple CSS pages and multiple js documents and optimise them I.e minify the content and get rid of duplicate tags I.e

.header{
Color:#000000;
}
.test{
Color:#000000;
}
Into
.header, .test{
Color:#000000;
}

And minify the CSS, not sure if this is what you are looking for but I'm sure if you optimise too much you will spend much more time then is worth on the optimisation as the speed you maybe increasing maybe only 0.001 second.

Comment: Indeed I am just using `csso` to crunch the CSS, it does something absurd on what I have so far (8538 bytes turns into 232 gzipped bytes) . It just makes me giddy.  And, yes. I think mobile is important to take into account. E.g. I know there are those situations on weak 3G (or EDGE) signals where this is going to be the difference between loading and not loading. It just so happens the app I'm working on is specifically for mobile.

Comment: Remember however if the site is for desktop aswell don't forget your cononical and alternative text (cononical tag on mobile site pointing to desktop site and vise versa for the mobile site but using alternative tag as it helps search engines firstly not duplicate the content and helps them to better understand your website.

Comment: Also don't foget to resize and compress your images so they are optimised for mobile sites, and I think w3c state the site should be less then 23kb